# Cannot boot from LiveUSB: “aufs mount failed”

Tags: 10.04, boot, ubuntu-netbook, live-usb, eeepc

I used [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to install an Ubuntu 10.04 Netbook LiveCD image on an SD Card. During this installation, I indicated that I wanted a persistent LiveUSB with 4GB dedicated to customization/settings.

The installation seems to finish without incident. However, when I try to boot from the SD card using my EeePC 901, Ubuntu fails to start I get the following message:

```
(initramfs) mount: mounting aufs on /root failed: No such device.
Aufs mount failed
```

What can I do to make my installation successfully boot?

Comment: Please note that what I'm going for here is a live session with changes saved to a file or partition of the SD card dedicated to preserving the file system. This is different from a full install which drastically reduces the performance and life of the SD card because of volume of write operations performed in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a livecd Using UNetbootin, download it from the USC, and run it, once it loads you can select the distro you would like to make a livecd of,or of you already have the iso you can choose it, then select your SD card and off you go.

[image]

Also you can **Install** UNR on the SD card , of course if there is enough space for it, and if you have another USB device.

To Install the OS on the SD card this is what i did (you need 2 USB devices or 2 SD card with 4GB+ available):

1. Create a livecd using UNetbootin
2. Connect both devices to your PC
3. Make sure you select the livecd to boot into it
4. Once you're on the livecd mount the other USB/SD device
5. Format it to ext4 or w/e Filesystem you want to use
6. Make Sure that you choose the USB/SD card when asked where to install Ubuntu (i unplugged my HDD's to avoid any confusion, but just by looking at the GB count you'll know )
7. Now you must wait for it to finish, since it is an SD card it will take like 2 hours or more. (when i installed it, i chose not to install updates or 3rd party , 'cause it's going to take more time)

Comment: Thanks, Uri, but this does not provide a persistent install. Any documents and settings I store on the flash drive disappear every time I reboot.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I was under the impression that a persistent live session is different from a full intallation. Is this true?

Comment: yes it is different a live session only keeps the data for as long as the session lasts, it resets any change you make to it after reboot